# Change text on jquery-loadingModal

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to change the text that's being shown when using the [jquery-loadingModal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-loadingModal) plugin, while the modal is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').loadingModal({  
    text: 'Showing loader animations...',
    'animation': 'wanderingCubes'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('body').loadingModal('text', 'My changed text');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".jquery-loading-modal__text").html('newtext...');
```